# Matlab FTP server client

Tags: matlab, ftp, ftp-client

I want download a specific file from FTP to my desktop so I used this code:

```
ftp_client = ftp('IP','Username','PASS');

mget(ftp_client,'/First_folder/WW.txt','F:/Target_Folder');
```

But when I use it, Matlab create a folder in F:/Target_Folder (with the name of First_folder) that contain WW.txt file. I want only have WW.txt in F:/Target_Folder without any folder in it. What should I do?

This is easy in URL style :

```
urlwrite('URL_Address/First_folder/WW.txt','F:/Target_Folder/TEXT.txt');
```

But when I use FTP I have this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change working folder using [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftp.cd.html)

```
ftp_client = ftp('IP','Username','PASS');
cd(ftp_client, 'Fisrt_folder');
mget(ftp_client,'WW.txt','F:/Target_Folder');
```